# Editing multiple *.xlsx files

Tags: vba, excel

Aim: do the same modification for multiple files.

Error: (Run-time error '13': Type mismatch) at line >Enter_Formulas wb

```
Option Explicit

Sub ProcessFiles()

Dim Filename, Pathname As String
Dim wb As Workbook

Pathname = "C:\Users\E\Desktop\macro2\"
Filename = Dir(Pathname)
Do While Filename <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename)
    Enter_Formulas wb

    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Filename = Dir()
Loop    
End Sub


Sub Enter_Formulas(wb As Workbooks)
With wb
    .Worksheets(1).Range("G19", Range("F19").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[0]C[-2]<0,R[-1]C[-5])"
    .Worksheets(1).Range("H19", Range("F19").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 2)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[0]C[-3]<0,R[-1]C[-5])"
    .Worksheets(1).Range("I19", Range("F19").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 3)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[0]C[-4]<0,R[-1]C[-5])"

    .Worksheets(1).Range("H7").FormulaR1C1 = "=ROUND(R[10]C,0)=ROUND(RC[-6],0)"
End With
End Sub
```

Note: sub procedure works if the body at `Enter_Formulas()` is: 
`.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "pointless"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot rely on default active worksheets for parent worksheet references.

```
.Worksheets(1).Range("G19", Range("F19").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[0]C[-2]<0,R[-1]C[-5])"
```

Range("F19") only belongs to Worksheets(1) if Worksheets(1) is the active worksheet. It is easy enough to fully qualify the parent worksheet.

```
Sub Enter_Formulas(wb As Workbooks)
    With wb.Worksheets(1)
        .Range(.cells(19, "G"), .cells(19, "F").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[0]C[-2]<0,R[-1]C[-5])"
        .Range(.cells(19, "H"), .cells(19, "F").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 2)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[0]C[-3]<0,R[-1]C[-5])"
        .Range(.cells(19, "I"), .cells(19, "F").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 3)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[0]C[-4]<0,R[-1]C[-5])"

        .Range("H7").FormulaR1C1 = "=ROUND(R[10]C,0)=ROUND(RC[-6],0)"
    End With
End Sub
```

Note `.Range("F19")` now, not `Range("F19")`.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
   Sub Enter_Formulas(wb As Workbooks)
```

to

```
   Sub Enter_Formulas(wb As Workbook)
```

(there is an extra "s" at the end in your declaration)

Comment: I did that and a new error occurs: Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error at 
   >.Worksheets(1).Range("G19", Range("F_____